# движение объекта

Tags: javascript

Есть объект, при нажатии перед ним он движется вперед (вправо), при нажатии позади него - назад (влево).

```
var car = document.querySelector(".car");
var road = document.querySelector(".road");
car.style.left = '1px';

var go = new Object;
go = {
    right : function(){
        car.style.left = parseInt(car.style.left) + 20 + 'px';
    },
    left : function(){
        car.style.left = parseInt(car.style.left) - 20 + 'px';
    }
}

road.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var value = Math.round(e.pageX) + 'px';
    if(value > car.style.left){
        go.right();
    }
    if(value < car.style.left){
        go.left();
    }
}, false)
```

Но какое бы значение не передавал курсор (сзади или спереди объекта) он движется только влево. Подскажите как решить этот недочет?

Comment: Я думаю это потому, что вы сравниваете не числа, а строки. У вас получается что-то типа `if ('20px' > '13px')`, а нужно сравнить именно числа, а потом уже добавлять куда нужно пиксели

Comment: точно! спасибо Алексей.
'road.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 var value = Math.round(e.pageX);
 if(value > car.style.left.split('px')[0]){
  go.right();
 }
 if(value < car.style.left.split('px')[0]){
  go.left();
 }
}, false)'

Comment: @Веня, небольшой оффтоп: `new Object` эквивалентно `{}`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if(value > car.style.left){
> ```

```
if(value > parseInt(car.style.left, 10)) {
```

И остальные места аналогично.

Comment: тогда и про эту строчку надо сказать: `var value = Math.round(e.pageX) + 'px';` :-)

Comment: @Grundy, да, точно.